# Android text recognition - Throttling the text recognizer

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, android-vision

I'm testing the android vision text recognizer, and in real-time use, the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text##performance_tips) suggest I "Throttle calls to the text recognizer. If a new video frame becomes available while the text recognizer is running, drop the frame."

In the sample [ocr-reader](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/ocr-reader) app, which shares the `CameraSource` and `OcrDetectorProcessor` with the [ML Kit](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) sample app, I'm trying to figure out precisely how this is accomplished. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm lookng at the `CameraPreviewCallback` and `FrameProcessingRunnable` classes, but no progress yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question, but I managed to do it like this: it is quite "manual", the idea is to have a flag before passing the processImage to your detector.

```
private var isProcessing = AtomicBoolean(false)

private fun process(image: FirebaseVisionImage) {
        isProcessing.set(true)
        detector.processImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { texts ->
                processTextRecognitionResult(texts)
                isProcessing.set(false)
            }

            .addOnFailureListener {
                println("Detection failed with $it")
            }
    }
```

So basically

```
override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy?, degrees: Int) {
        imageProxy?.image?.let { image ->
            if(!isProcessing.get()) {
               process(image)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to learn Kotlin - thanks for the idea, I'll try it out in the next week or so.

Comment: You would want to set isProcessing to false on failure as well I think, unless you want to stop processing on failure. Adding this listener .addOnCompleteListener { isProcessing.set(false) } would be best, instead of adding isProcessing.set(false) to each listener.